# How do I create a list of date intervals in python?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm making a call to an API which allows me to enter the start and end date in the request url, each request needs a date range to be within a 31 day?

is it possible to loop through a date range like the example below?

```
max_start_date   =  '2017-01-01'
max_end_date =   '2017-12-31'
```

The first loop will return `'2017-01-01'` to `'2017-01-31'` and the 2nd loop should return `'2017-02-01'` to `'2017-03-03'`

```
url = "https://api.awin.com/publishers/{}/transactions/?startDate={}T00%3A00%3A00&endDate={}0T01%3A59%3A59&timezone=UTC&accessToken={}".format(publisher_id, start_date, end_date,token)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `datetime` module:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

start = date(2017, 1, 1)
end = date(2017, 12, 31)

while start < end:
    print(start, start + timedelta(days=31))
    start += timedelta(days=31)
```

If you need to loop through calendar months, consider using `relativedelta` from `dateutil`:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

while start < end:
    print(start, start + relativedelta(months=1))
    start += relativedelta(days=31)
```

(you need to install it by running `pip install dateutil`)

Docs:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html
- https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following for a list of dates:

```
import datetime as dt
max_start_date = '2017-01-01'
max_end_date = '2017-12-31'

def dt_range(*args):
    """
    Args are positional, though you could probably 
    toss in an evaluation part to determine which is the min date.
    """
    dt_start = dt.datetime.strptime(args[0], '%Y-%m-%d')
    dt_end = dt.datetime.strptime(args[1], '%Y-%m-%d')
    for i in range(int((dt_end - dt_start).days)+1):
        yield dt_start + dt.timedelta(i)


for i in dt_range(max_start_date, max_end_date):
    print(i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```